# A shell script for passing argument to a perl script

Tags: shell

I am completely new to shell scripting and would really appreciate some help. Basically I want to pass a log path as argument in a shell script. Can anybody please explain to me how to do this?. A sample code would be appreciated.

Edit - I need an sh code that would pass an argument to the perl code .

Comment: Indeed, sample code would be nice.  It's not even clear if you want `perl` code or `sh` code.

Comment: I need an sh code that would pass an argument to the perl code .

Comment: `perl $path` would seem to do it, then.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a perl script named, e.g., `script.pl`, you would pass it an argument like this:

```
$ perl script.pl arg1
```

Or, if `script.pl` is executable and in your `$PATH`, then simply:

```
$ script.pl arg1
```

Inside your perl script, you can access the command line arguments as indexes of the global `@ARGV` array.  So to print out the first argument to your script, the code would look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "First argument: ", $ARGV[0], "\n";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed expalantion , now supposingly i pass a directory path from a java class to shell script , and the script should make it possible to navigate to that path , what do we do , is this right cd "$1"    ??