# How to cross over a file from Shell to Perl, and back to Shell

Tags: bash, perl, shell, sorting, call

I am making a Shell Script that will prompt the user for a file that contains 50 words or more, and upon checking whether it is a file that exists in the same directory. It will then bring up a menu asking if the user wants to sort the file using shell, sort the file using a perl script, search the file for a word that is prompted from the user and then will say what line that word is on, or exit.  **What I am stumped on is how I can bring over the file prompted for in the Shell script, to the two perl scripts.**  Currently I have them hardcoded to take in a list of words that is in the same directory 'fiftywords.txt', but if a user wants to use their list it has to be a variable name.  But I don't think I can just call over 'filename' from shell to perl, because perl doesn't know what that is.

"As with the shell script, the Perl script will sort the file, but the shell script is responsible for writing the sorted data to another file."  **So not only do I have to bring it from shell to perl, after sorting it, somehow allow Shell to take back over and put the sorted result into the new output file.**  I would like to know how to do this as well.  This is a homework assignment, but I am held back by finishing it because I don't understand how to go from shell to perl, then back to shell.  The convention will probably be similar for the search program.  If I passed 'filename' as an argument when calling perl sort.pl, will that bring it's data over to the perl script?

Main Shell program:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
printf "Hello. \nPlease input a filename for a file containing a list of words you would like to     use.  Please allow for one word per line.\n -> "
read filename
printf "You have entered the filename: $filename.\n"

if [ -f "$filename" ] #check if the file even exists in the current directory to use
then
    printf "The file $filename exists.  What would you like to do with this file?\n\n"
else
    printf "The file: $filename, does not exist.  Rerun this shell script and please enter a     valid file with it's proper file extension.  An example of this would be mywords.txt \n\nNow  exiting.\n\n"
    exit
fi

printf "Main Menu\n"
printf "=========\n"
printf "Select 1 to sort file using Shell and output to a new file.\n"
printf "Select 2 to sort file using Perl and output to a new file.\n"
printf "Select 3 to search for a word using Perl.\n"
printf "Select 4 to exit.\n\n"

echo "Please enter your selection below"
read selection
printf "You have selected option $selection.\n"

if [ $selection -eq "1" ]
then
    read -p "What would you like to call the new file? "  newfile   #asks user what they want to     call the new file that will have the sorted list outputted to it
    sort $filename > $newfile
    echo "Your file: $newfile, has been created."
fi

if [ $selection -eq "2" ]
then
    read -p "What would you like to call the new file? "  newfile2
    perl sort.pl    #open Perl script 1 that sorts the file
    # $filefromsort.pl > $newfile2  #put the sorted list into the new output file that the user specificed with newfile2
fi

if [ $selection -eq "3" ]
then
    perl search.pl    #open Perl script 2 that searches the list of words in the file; this one     should just return that it can't find the word or the line it found the word on
fi

if [ $selection -eq "4" ]
then
    printf "Now exiting.\n\n"
    exit
fi
```

Perl Script that will take in the file inputted in Shell and sort it, and then have Shell output it to a new file of the user's choice (incomplete because I don't know how to bring the file from shell over):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

#take in the old file list that was passed in from the shell script

sort $filename > $newfile2       #sort the old list passed in from the shell script

#somehow give Shell control again to put the sorted data into the new file that the user was prompted for in the shell script selection 2
```

Perl script that will search for the word the user wants to find what line it's on (this works on the hardcoded list, but I need to know how to use the file from the shell script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$count = 1;     #global variable for return value
                # of words.

#use filename given at start of shell script and print out the list of words in that file to prove that we opened it

open (myfile, 'fiftywords.txt');        #is supposed to open the file taken in from the shell     script,     fiftywords.txt
                                    # is hardcoded for testing purposes currently
while (<myfile>)
{
    print "$_";
}
close (myfile);
#Now that we have opened the file, printed off everything for the user to see, they can now enter  a word in a prompt to
# see what line it is on.

$filename = 'fiftywords.txt';
printf "\nPlease enter the word you want to search for\n";
$word = <STDIN>;
chomp $word;

open FILE,"<$filename" or die "Cannot read the file $filename: $!\n";

while ($line = <FILE>)
{
    if ($line =~ m/$word/)
    {
       print "$word has been found on line $count.\n\n";
    }
    if ($line !=~ m/$word/)
    {
       $count++;
    }
    else
    {
       print "$word cannot be found.";
    }
}
close (FILE);
```

List of 50+ words (doesn't matter what words they are):

```
taco
burger
gum
loudspeaker
nailpolish
door
bottle
lotion
pinata
tan
hydrate
earthquake
juice
feather
spaceship
clover
peanut
tar
cassette
butter
gracious
cloud
elevator
meandering
worship
plow
quilt
flower
tone
elope
smell
tower
question
trance
flavor
erosion
jeep
aardvark
carrot
deep
festive
grape
yellow
artist
rake
rock
jam
whole
jester
kite
mouse
elixir
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A shell script for passing argument to a perl script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258227/a-shell-script-for-passing-argument-to-a-perl-script)

Comment: That may explain how to go from shell to perl, but for the Perl sort program, I pass it to the perl program, sort it, then pass it back to shell again.  How do I pass the sorted list back to shell?

Comment: "How do I pass the sorted list back to shell?" Have your Perl script send the sorted lines to standard output?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, that's totally okay, but you might want to mention that in your question. And if it's not homework, just ignore this comment :)

Comment: It is homework, but I did a good portion of the grunt work and I understand the logic behind it, but we were expected to understand shell and perl from 2, 40 minute video lectures that barely helped.    I just don't understand most of the syntax and I think i'm pretty close, hence why I am I asking for help now and I'm stuck even after using google and this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shell:

```
perl sort.pl "$filename"
```

perl:

```
my $filename = shift @ARGV;
```

Comment: So shift will take original file as the argument from the shell script and put it into a private variable $filename?

Comment: Yes, that's what he's saying. `@ARGV` contains the arguments passed to the script.